# If $E_k$ is a decreasing sequence of closed nonempty sets of a complete metric space whose diameter converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

then the intersection consists of exactly one point. I can show that the intersection is nonempty, but I couldn't proves it's just one point. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if $x,y\in\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}E_k$ with $x\neq y$, then, for each $k\in\mathbb N$, $x,y\in E_k$ and therefore $\operatorname{diam}E_k\geqslant d(x,y)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let two points $x$ and $y$ be in the intersection. Since they are different, their distance $d(x,y)$ is larger than some $\varepsilon >0$.

Can you continue?